# Auto load Zend forms inside a module

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I have a very strange problem.  I need to load all the resources of the couple of modules.

I have these line inside the `application.ini`.

```
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.modules[] =  ""
```

The problem is it works perfectly well for 2 modules i have created including model and form are loading with out any issue. Then I created third module, it is loading the controller with out any problem,  but it is throwing the fatal error when i try to call the Form class inside that module.

```
Fatal error: Class 'Test_Form_Test' not found in /xx/application/modules/test/controllers/IndexController.php on line 14
```

Is there any restriction on how many modules resources you can load?  What is the problem?

Comment: I have solved the issue. You have to declare the Bootstrap class inside each of the modules as well.  SOLVED!